# Reading multiple rows with SQL reader

Tags: c#, sql-server

So here is the code I currently have, when reading one result from a table works fine,

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    newValue = reader.GetString(0);
    newPageID = reader.GetInt32(1);
}
```

However, the problem comes when there are multiple rows that are being returned. The way I tried to do this was like so,

```
int counter = 0;
List<Trigger> TriggerValues = new List<Trigger>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    TriggerValues.Add(new Trigger(reader.GetString(counter), reader.GetInt32(counter+1)));
    counter++;

}
```

But this does not work, which I think is because reader will only return one row. Is there a simple way to modify what I have here to read in new objects row by row?
Thanks.

Comment: "But this does not work" -- what results are you seeing?  how does it "not work"?

Comment: Looks right to me.  You sure that multiple rows are being returned?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If I did not overlook something severe what you posted should work. Maybe your query simply does only return one row?

Comment: datareader reads one row per each iteration until reading whole rows, you need to use it correctly or use a dataadaptor to fill the whole rows in a source like datatable or dataset or etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at `GetString(0)` `GetInt32(1)`, `0` and `1` are the column index, not row. So you should leave it and remove `counter`

```
List<Trigger> TriggerValues = new List<Trigger>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    TriggerValues.Add(new Trigger(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1)));
}
```

Comment: Good spot given that no error information was in the question.

Comment: Ah this works perfectly. I was thinking that they referred to rows.

Comment: Was just waiting for the time limit xD

Answer (score 4):

Everytime you execute `reader.Read()`, you are loading a new row.  The indices you are supplying to the `.GetString()` and `.GetInt32()` functions is a column index, not a row index.

You simply need to call

```
List<Trigger> TriggerValues = new List<Trigger>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    TriggerValues.Add(new Trigger(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1)));
}
```